# How to get data with the related table in slick and quill without join?

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, quill

I'm working with scala, mysql, slick and quill.

This is my one to many tables. (1 employee has many assets)

```
Employee Table
+-------------+-------+--------+
| employee_id | name  | salary |
+-------------+-------+--------+
|      1      |   A   |   50   |
|      2      |   B   |   42   |
|      5      |   C   |   28   |
|      8      |   D   |   61   |
+-------------+-------+--------+

Asset Table
+----------+----------+-------------+
| asset_id |   name   | employee_id |
+----------+----------+-------------+
|    1     | mouse    |      1      |
|    2     | keyboard |      1      |
|    3     | monitor  |      1      |
|    5     | keyboard |      2      |
|    6     | mouse    |      5      |
|    8     | mouse    |      8      |
+----------+----------+-------------+
```

This is my quill case classes for above tables.

```
case class Employee(employee_id: Int, name: String, salary: Int)
```

```
case class Asset(asset_id: Int, name: String, employee_id: Int)
```

This is query generation method for view all employees.

```
def viewAll: Future[List[Employee]] ={
  val viewAllEmployees = quote{
    query[Employee]
  }

  val result = ctx.run(viewAllEmployees)
  result
}
```

This is main method calling above function.

```
val result = viewAllEmployees
result.onComplete{
  case result =>  printList(result.get)
}
```

Within this I can get list of employee objects, but I want to employee objects with relevant asset objects. With a join query I can do that, But I want the results without joins.
I'm looking for answer with both quill and slick.